# Why is my selected state not preserved when called setSelected on tableview cell?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

So i came to this slight bump in the road. I created a custom tableview cell, in the tableviw cell class i override `[tableViewCell setSelected:TRUE animated:FALSE]`. In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method i check some logic and if the logic is true then set the cell as selected using [`tableViewCell setSelected:TRUE animated:FALSE];` All if fine and dandy until i realized this. The system is calling `[tableviewCell setSelected]` implicitly after i explicitlty call `setSelected`. When the system calls it my selected state is set to false when i explicitly set it to true. I know its the same tableview cell since im checking its memory location using self. I found an answer to fix this issue but it really makes no sense as to why this is happening. if I call `[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:FALSE scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];` the setSelected method is not called twice and it preserves the selected state i have set on the cell in my logic. So why does this way work and not just setting the cells selected state?

Comment: It's the table view's job to set the selected state of its cells, it doesn't like it when you change them behind its back

Comment: Then why do they allow us to call `setSelected` if they would rather have us just call `[tableview selectRowAtIndexPath animated]` doesnt make any sense to even expose those methods to us

Answer (score 1):

You can set selected state from did select delegate method

```
let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
cell.isSelected = true
```

it will automatically select and deselect cell